# Setting lil_matrix elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Why does the following code not set the elements of the row in the `lil_matrix`?

```
    for i in range(k):
        val = random.uniform(0, math.sqrt(5.0/float(k)))
        print val
        q[movie_id, i] = val
    print repr(q.getrow(movie_id))
```

The output is

```
0.409419926697
0.0738510208877
0.389643102199
0.196197313266
0.455269767754
0.0180136881495
0.477090181128
0.20090686778
0.219917573507
0.239565179724
0.287646325115
0.370173110788
0.354909675867
0.328178740109
0.393251208887
0.0526814336142
0.357039191946
0.493527054114
0.318013696588
0.0736954887361
<1x20 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int8'>'
        with 0 stored elements in LInked List format>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your matrix is of dtype `int8`, but you're trying to store floating-point values in it. NumPy rounds the values to `0`, then finds that since this is a sparse matrix, the zeros should not be explicitly stored.

Did you mean to construct a matrix of floating-point dtype?